# Submit event on input field in a form

Tags: javascript, forms, dom-events, submit

Came across a code in which the `submit()` event has been applied to the input field in the form.
Something like:

```
$("#foo").click(function(){
    $("#formID input").submit();
})
```

where `"#foo"` is a dynamically created list element. Does this submit only the input field and not the entire form?

Comment: I'd assume it throws a ReferenceError, since input elements do not have a `submit` method.

Comment: @Touffy — It isn't an undeclared variable, so it wouldn't trigger a reference error. If the property didn't exist then it would complain that `undefined` is not a function. jQuery instances do have `submit` methods though.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right, it would be a TypeError. Didn't know much about jQuery. Now I checked, it will actually dispatch a 'submit' event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is being called without any arguments, it will trigger a submit event.

This will bubble and trigger any submit event handlers on that element and any of its ancestors.

It will not trigger any native submission of data (that would require the method to be called on a form element).